# Swagger - Add on extra details for referenced params

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0

So I have a path that is using a referenced param, but the referenced param isn't `required: true`, which I would like to add on. I thought I could use the following syntax for that:

`operationId: getReports
summary: Get the reports 
parameters:
  - $ref: '#/parameters/reportStartDate'
    required:true
  - $ref: '#/parameters/reportEndDate'
    required:true`

However, this doesn't seem to work the way I would expect. It also seems that I can't use `allOf`, since that only works for combining too objects.

Does anyone have a way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Properties of `$ref`'d parameters cannot be overridden. You'll need to redefine the parameter entirely.